# AVPlayer performance - videos are flickering when scrolling a list fast

Tags: ios, avplayer

I have a list of 60 videos which I'd like to display on a list and play while a user is scrolling. 
Unfortunately when I'm scrolling the list fast, the view is totally unusable - the video players flicker and there is a serious delay in scrolling (e.g. app freezes for half a second before rendering players and shows just empty cells).

I tried using threads, but it didn't help much. Code snippet from my last tries looked roughly this way:

```
    cell.videoSnippetPlayerView!.hidden = true
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE.value), 0)) {
        cell.setVideo(urlString, rowNo: indexPath.row)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            cell.videoSnippetPlayerView!.hidden = false
        }
    }
```

I used local video files (resources), so there is no delay caused by network.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes - my conclusion was that AVPlayer uses main thread heavily therefore there is no way to make it smooth... 
I created my own layer and used avcodec to decode H264 stream and OpenGL to render frames onto the layer. It was a lot of work, but now runs smoothly :)  I also recommend looking at Video Toolbox framework.